# \setmainfont works with XeTeX but not with LuaTeX

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec

I'm trying to use LuaTeX with Adobe's Garamond Premier Pro, but it doesn't work, saying that:

```
! error:  (type 0): cannot find file ''
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

while XeTeX compiles fine.

I managed to narrow down the issue to the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro}
\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

I'm using TeXLive 2018.

Following Ulrike's suggestion, I changed the font name by the file name:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
% \setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro}
\setmainfont{GaramondPremrPro.otf}
\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

this didn't work as well :/

So I tried copying `GaramondPremrPro.otf` from the installed directory (`$HOME/.local/share/fonts/`) to the current directory, then it worked (it also works if I put them in a directory in the texmf tree). So I guess that the problem is with Ubuntu's font directory...

---

Addendum: Something I think it's odd...

Suppose I have only the file `GaramondPremrPro.otf` in the current directory and call the font by the file name:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
% \setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro}
\setmainfont{GaramondPremrPro.otf}
\begin{document}
hello
\bfseries
hello
\end{document}
```

I get a only font substitution warning because LaTeX couldn't find the bold font file:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/GaramondPremrPro.otf(0)/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/GaramondPremrPro.otf(0)/m/n' instead on input line 7.
```

However, if I call the font by its name:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro}
% \setmainfont{GaramondPremrPro.otf}
\begin{document}
hello
\bfseries
hello
\end{document}
```

I get the cryptic `cannot find file ''` from above.

If I remove the `\bfseries` instruction, both versions work.

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: which fontloader version? And where is the font?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm not sure where do I find that. I think it's `2018/09/24 2.90001`. I installed the font using Ubuntu's font manager thing (double click the font, click "Install"). All programs (that I checked) see the font normally. Here's the log: https://pastebin.com/5kUruNaj

Comment: @Thérèse Thanks for checking. I just did `tlmgr update --list` and got `tlmgr: no updates available`, no I guess it's not a version issue...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just found the fonts to be installed at `$HOME/.local/share/fonts` :)

Comment: If lualatex wouldn't find the font at all the error message would be different. What happens if you use the file name with extension (something like `\setmainfont{xxx.otf}`)?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer See my edit (too long for a comment :). One thing that I find strange is that it says `cannot find file ''`. Another thing that I think is strange is that XeTeX _does_ find the font at `$HOME/.local/share/fonts`... I saw you released an update of `luaotfload` yesterday. Should update to see what happens or should I wait?

Comment: Have you tried `\setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro}[Path = $HOME/.local/share/fonts/]`?

Comment: The update wouldn't change the way luaotfload searches fonts, it address some other problems. Search by font name is different in xelatex and lualatex. Do other fonts in this folder work? You could also check your font in the name database \texmf-var\luatex-cache\generic\names and check if there are other fonts with this name which could confuse luaotfload.

Comment: @Mico Just tried it. Using the _font_ name I get `"File not found: /home/phelype/.local/share/fonts/GaramondPremierPro."`. Apparently it thinks that when the `Path` is given the name is that of the file. Using the _file_ name instead, I get both the font substitution warning when I use `\bfseries` _and_ the `cannot find file ''`. I'm definitely confused :/

Comment: Just saw the edit: the behaviour with \bfseries means that fontspec can't really identify the corresponding bold font. That can happen (font names are sometimes odd) and you can resolve this by using the BoldFont option.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, other fonts do work. I tried `Adobe Caslon Pro`, `Cooper Black BT`, and `Junicode` and they all work. I looked at the directory you mentioned and found two files (and a `.luc` with the same name): `luaotfload-lookup-cache.lua` which contains entries for both `CooperBlackBT` and `Junicode`, but nothing about `Adobe Caslon Pro` or `Garamond Premier Pro`; and `luaotfload-names.lua.gz` which contains entries on lots of fonts, including `adobecaslonpro`, `cooperblackbt`, `junicode`, _and_ `garamondpremierpro`. None gave me a clue...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer About the `\bfseries` thing: I know about `BoldFont`, but I preferred to use the font by the name because then the different weights and shapes are automatically set up (there are 34 of them, half of which I don't know what they are for :P).

Comment: Hm. Can you search your system for a file `GaramondPremrPro` with another extension?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sure :) With `sudo find / -name '*GaramondPremrPro*'` I only got `/home/jlester/.local/share/fonts/GaramondPremrPro.otf` and its variants: `GaramondPremrPro-Bd.otf`, `GaramondPremrPro-It.otf`, etc. Nothing else...

Comment: Your font is now in another folder, not phelype but jlester? But beside this I'm quite cueless. If other fonts in the folder work, the folder should be ok, if the font works in other locations the font should be ok. You could add `\directlua{luaotfload.log.set_loglevel (6)}` to your document, perhaps you then get something useful in the log. (compare it with the log of some other font in the folder).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry the delay, I had a meeting. Sorry about the user name confusion, the first one was a test on a coworker's computer. I tried your suggestion, but the logs for Caslon and Garamond are very similar, except for the part where Garamond breaks... I'm lost.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm useless. Just noticed I forgot to show the logs... Here's the one for Caslon: https://pastebin.com/TWHj18Wt and the one for Garamond: https://pastebin.com/vLWLKetF both generated with the first code in the question (calling the font by its name) plus the `\directlua` line before the `\documentclass`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84068/discussion-between-ulrike-fischer-and-john-doe-nut).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that one of the cache files was broken.

After deleting the cache files in

`/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/`

and in

`/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl`

and letting luaotfload recreate everything the font could be used.