# error with font paths

Tags: fontspec, compilation-error

I have a situation regarding font paths. Something is not using the specified path and it causes a critical failure at the pdf build step. What is strange is that the the fonts seem to have been correctly selected as indicated further up in the log. I am going to highlight that my font path is `../font/` as these are `standalone` files which exist in a subdirectory. I use a switch option in my package file. When I run the compilation from main everything works correctly.

package path option switch

```
\def\mypath{..}

\DeclareOption{main}{%
    \def\mypath{.}%
}%
```

file structure

```
main.tex
  |font/
    |EurostileLTStd-condenced.otf
    |EurostileLTStd-demioblique.otf
  |chapters/
    |standalonefile.tex
  |images/
    |background.png
  |mypackage.sty
```

line 236, illustrating correctly specified font paths

```
(fontspec)             'EurostileLTStd' with options [Path =
(fontspec)             ../font/,Extension = {.otf},UprightFont =
(fontspec)             {*-condenced},BoldFont = {*-demioblique}].
```

Here is the error, at the very last part of the log.

line 1457

```
 78 fonts using 6816975 bytes
 128i,15n,123p,627b,1102s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
! error:  (file ) (type 0): cannot find file ''
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

And I know whats happening but not how to fix it. The path of the fonts are not being preserved or respected. If I add a copy of the `font/` directory to the chapters directory (which is a subdirectory for `standalone` files) the compilation is successful, and you can see in the log the paths have changed from what I specified. Keep in mind I did not alter the path specification between the two builds, and the font loading path logged on lines 236 did not change.

line 236, note how these still properly read `../font/`

```
(fontspec)             'EurostileLTStd' with options [Path =
(fontspec)             ../font/,Extension = {.otf},UprightFont =
(fontspec)             {*-condenced},BoldFont = {*-demioblique}].
```

line 1457, showing that the path is now `./font/`

```
 78 fonts using 6816975 bytes
 128i,15n,123p,627b,1102s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
<./font/EurostileLTStd-demioblique.otf><./font/EurostileLTStd-condenced.otf>
Output written on main.pdf (1 page, 27356 bytes).
```

As a final note, I use the same path switch for loading images from images directory, and these work just fine.

These are compiled with lualatex.

Comment: I want to add that I looked at this question with a similar error, and the directory `luatex-cache` the posted solution do not exist.
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453468/setmainfont-works-with-xetex-but-not-with-luatex

Comment: Your description is a bit unclear, but pathes are relative to the location where you start the compilation, so normally you can't use the same setting if you compile from different folder levels. Side remark: I would install the fonts in a texmf tree or the system and not use the path key at all.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I use the switch option \usepackage[main]{mypackage} while compiling from main.tex to ensure that paths are correct. What specifics remain unclear, I will do my best to edit the question. I need the document to be portable, compilable from a single zip file that carries the fonts with it.